# How to pass the value entered in a text box from a modal window to another component using Blazor server?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am working on a Blazor server project and created this modal window. This is a component itself

```
        <div class="modal @ModalClass" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display:@ModalDisplay">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"  @onclick="() => Close()">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <label for="FirstName">Enter FirstName:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="FirstName" name="FirstName"><br><br>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => Done()">Done</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" @onclick="() => Close()">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        @if (ShowBackdrop)
        {
            <div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>
        }


        @code {
            public Guid Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
            public string ModalDisplay = "none;";
            public string ModalClass = "";
            public bool ShowBackdrop = false;

            public void Open()
            {
                ModalDisplay = "block;";
                ModalClass = "Show";
                ShowBackdrop = true;
                StateHasChanged();
            }

            public void Close()
            {
                ModalDisplay = "none";
                ModalClass = "";
                ShowBackdrop = false;
                StateHasChanged();
            }

            public void Done()
            {
                
            }
        }
```

I am using the component like this. I want to be able to use the `FirstName` entered in the Modal
in this component below to do other things when the user clicks on <kbd>Done</kbd> button.

```
        @page "/modaltest"

        <MappingPoc.UI.Pages.MyModal @ref="Modal"></MappingPoc.UI.Pages.MyModal>


        <button @onclick="() => Modal.Open()">Open Modal</button>

        @code {
            private MappingPoc.UI.Pages.MyModal Modal { get; set; }
        }
```

How can I pass the value of the first name entered in the modal to this component?

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Yes. I like your approach. It also works in the fiddle. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [EventCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0#eventcallback) to achieve this.

- In your `Modal` component, bind the first name input textbox to a field using the `@bind` attribute:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <label for="FirstName">Enter FirstName:</label>
    <input @bind="firstName" type="text" id="FirstName" name="FirstName"><br><br>
</div>
```

- In the `@code` section of the same component, define a field called `firstName` of type `string`:

```
private string firstName;
```

- This `firstName` will be bound to the textbox and any value update in the textbox will also set the value of `firstName` to the same value.
- Secondly, in the same code section, add a `public` property of type `EventCallback<string>` as a parameter to the `Modal` component(by decorating it with the `[Parameter]` attribute:

```
[Parameter] public EventCallback<string> OnDoneCallback { get; set; }
```

- In this code section, invoke the `EventCallback` using its `InvokeAsync()` method in the `Done()` method:

```
public void Done()
{
    // ...
    await InvokeAsync(() => OnDoneCallback.InvokeAsync(firstName));              
}
```

This is all you need in your child `Modal` component.

---

- In the `@code` section of the parent component, add a field to hold the first name from the child component:

```
private string _firstName;
```

- Now, include a callback method to be executed in response to when the `Done` method of the child component calls the `EventCallback`:

```
private void OnModalDone(string firstName)
{
                _firstName = firstName;
}
```

- Now in your parent component where you are including the `Modal` component, pass the `OnModalDone` method as parameter for the `EventCallback`:

```
<MappingPoc.UI.Pages.MyModal @ref="Modal" OnDoneCallback="OnModalDone"></MappingPoc.UI.Pages.MyModal>
<h1>@_firstName</h1>
```

- I have also added an `<h1>` tag to display the first name. Now, when you click the `Done` button of the modal, it will call the `Done` method. This `Done` method will call `OnModalDone` of the parent, with the parameter set as the value entered in the textbox of the modal. The entered value is available in `OnModalDone` as the parameter `firstName`.
- You don't need to call `StateHasChanged` for event callbacks, it is called automatically.

---

See this working in Blazor fiddle: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/rbsg30wv

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways you can do this depending on your needs:

Cascading Parameters: A good video for the basics of it - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZmDMKp1Q8kA

An AppState approach: A good video for it covering two different ways: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BB4lK2kfKf0

Or you can pass it in as a parameter to the component: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0 (scroll down to the 'Binding with component parameters' section

I included videos as I believe they are more helpful but let me know if it is not clear.